# i am trying to pass parameter to data through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typo3

I am trying to pass value through an ajax json array but value of catergory variable is not getting in controller action

```
var category = $('#category').val();
var url = $('#ajax_action_search').val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    'category': category
  },
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {}
});
```

Comment: add `url` in ajax and remove `cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,` if you are not sendig files.

Comment: i have added url

Comment: provided both action and controller name

Comment: Update your question with the codes related to controller action method and model class.

Comment: Provide the complete code, then only we could help you.

Comment: is it a <f:link.action or f:uri.action? And are you trying to pass the variable from the ajax to an action, or from an action to ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the parameter namespace matching your extension/plugin:

```js
$.ajax({
  // ...
  data: {
    'tx_myext_foo[category]': category,
  },
  // ...
});
```

But you'll also need to configure the `cHash` evaluation since this will lead to a HTTP request like `/?tx_myext_foo[category]=X` which will fail without a matching `cHash`.

This can be done with the [`excludedParameters` configuration option](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Important-81568-MigrateChashConfiguration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Controller action if `category` (parameter name) passed from the ajax is exactly same in the controller action too

```
var category = $('#category').val();
var url = $('#ajax_action_search').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify {
        category: category
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make ajaxurl with action and controller. and then pass the data in full format.

```
var ajaxUrl = '<f:uri.action action="youraction" controller="Yourcontroller" />';
var category = $('#category').val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data: '&tx_yourext_yourplugin[category]='+category,
    success: function(response) {
    },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make the following changes :

```
var category = $('#category').val();
var url = $('#ajax_action_search').val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:url,
  data: {'category': category},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {}
});
```

Comment: Kindly post value of URL and check in console for any errors. It should work properly.